# Pass a function to the KEY in a JavaPairRDD<K,V>

Tags: java, apache-spark, mapreduce, rdd

I'm working with the Spark API for Java. I have a JavaPairRDD where the key, k, is compressed as a sequence of bytes. I would like to pass the decompress-function (that I've already written) to the KEY (and not the value). The keys will still be unique after the decompression and I want them to be paired with their corresponding value, v.

One approach would be to `myHashMap = myPairRDD.collectAsMap()` and then `mySet = myHashMap.keySet()` but then it wouldn't be done in parallell anymore and the keys would be detached from their values.

Another approach would be to use `mySingleRDD = myPairRDD.keys()` but then the keys would be detached from their corresponding values, v.

Does anyone have a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

RDDs support two types of operations: *transformations*, which create a new dataset from an existing one, and *actions*, which return a value to the driver program after running a computation on the dataset.

For the presented issue, you should use `mapToPair`, which is a transformation that passes each JavaPairRDD element through a (uncompress) function and returns a new JavaPairRDD.
Each key/value entry on the result RDD is of type `Tuple2 <K, V>`.
In this, I used `Tuple2<Object, Object>` as key/value and also assumed you have *uncompress()* function for the keys:

**Java 8:**

```
JavaPairRDD<Object, Object> result = pairRDD.mapToPair( 
                (Tuple2<Object, Object> pair) ->  new Tuple2<Object, Object>(uncompress(pair._1()), pair._2()));
```

**Java 6/7:**  (can't avoid non-lambda hell...)

```
javaPair.mapToPair(new PairFunction<Tuple2<Object,Object>, Object, Object>() {
    @Override
    public Tuple2<Object, Object> call(Tuple2<Object, Object> pair) throws Exception {
        return new Tuple2<Object, Object>(uncompress(pair._1()), pair._2());
    }});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pseudo-code. Transform old RDD to a new RDD where the new RDD's key is uncompressed.

```
newRDD = oldRdd.map( (key, value) => (decompress(key), value) )
```